# How handle recyclerView body clickListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I can't handle clicks on recycerView body (**NOT ITEMS**),

but when I setOnClickListener on my recycler, it does not work.

I tried clickable="true" in xml, but does not work.

```
recycler.setOnClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Click on recyclerView",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a Touch Listener :

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            when (event.actionMasked) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    true
                }
                else -> false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass your click listener on "onBindViewHolder()"

That way you will be able to receive where the user clicked and perform something with it.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(LanguageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final String name = names.get(position);

        holder.main_item_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //do something
            }
        });
    }
```

And what you want to do is to set the click listener on your root layout from your items

Comment: You've got it wrong. I don't want to handle Item's click listener.I want to handle clicking on empty place of recycler body , like when recycler has 1 row and I want to handle clicking on bottom of that row. got it?